# Quote values in pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

what I want to achive is import dump of table from postgres database.

I used to dump table from database,

> sudo pg_dump -n 'productiondata' -t 'productiondata.labels_city' osm  -h
>   37.28.155.118 -U postgres > /f44/labels_city.sql

next I tried to import table with:

> psql -U postgres -h localhost osm < /f44/labels_city.sql

but I get an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "San" LINE 1: San Gregorio 12 20
>   11388757 0101000020110F0000B3ADAD6267CC60...

I think problem is with quotation marks in table values.
How should I modify command to quote table values?

Comment: compare `productiondata.labels_city` structure on both servers please

Comment: Structure on both is exactly the same.

Comment: if there's not much data, you can use `--inserts` with `pg_dump` to use inserts instead of copy

Comment: Based on the error, your file seems to consist purely of data, without SQL commands (and the mentioned invocation of `pg_dump` would not produce that).

Comment: SQL commands are included in file. LINE 1 is in fact LINE 1421532. Problem is with table values. There are too many quotemarks in values (Like in names: Al"Shaar) and postgres crashes trying to read them.

Comment: The "San Gregorio" and what follows looks like COPY data  that is interpreted as an SQL statement. This may happen when the COPY fails for any reason, but that failure would produce an error message before the syntax error you mention, with the actual reason. Only that first error message is of interest in this case.